# Pattern for handling Firebase models with relationships (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, nosql

I'm looking for examples of patterns in existing iOS apps (Swift preferred, but I guess it doesn't matter) to get some ideas on how to handle models when working with Firebase (or any NoSQL DB). The complication is due to 1) the way in which Firebase listens for changes to data, and 2) keeping the db request logic out of the models.

So let's say I have something like this:

```
struct User {
    let name: String
    let checkin: Checkin
}

struct Checkin {
    let name: String
    let coordinates: Double
}
```

Now when I decide I want data in my view controller, I'll do something like `Database.database()..reference()...` and have a method on my model parse the JSON and insert it into the model. Now what happens when it gets to a relationship property (in this case, `checkin` when creating an instance of `User`)? If I want the full user model with all child relationships, I'm only going to get back something like `{ checkin: someRandomCheckinId }` from Firebase. I *could* make another call to get the checkin by ID, but I'd have to do that logic in my model when parsing the data received from Firebase, which doesn't seem ideal - it seems that logic best belongs on the VC (or a separate data manager class called by the VC). Is there a better way?

Additionally, I want to be able to listen for changes given it's a main feature of Firebase. I can't imagine polluting my model with a bunch of listeners is a good thing.

Any examples of repos with a good pattern for this would be great to help wrap my head around an appropriate solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to this question. The first is how to structure data in a NoSQL document store. The second is how to structure an application in a modern OO language. Both expand well past the reach of Firebase and Swift.

For the first part, the advice I would give you to start with is that you should keep related data together for fast access. There is normally a space penalty when working with these type of databases as data is duplicated. This is ok as space is relatively cheap compared to time. In your example, if you often want to get all the 'Checkins' when you get a 'User' then store the 'Checkins' for a user in that user. If you are used to working with RDBs then you need to remember that with this type of storage, you can store layers of data and an attribute can have multiple values. Make sure you read the Firebase documentation on how data is accessed as they have some recommendations for how data should be stored to avoid wasting time and space. The main idea is to keep data flatter rather than too many layers deep and remember that getting a parent also gets all its children. This usually involves some data duplication.

For the second part of the question, you are going to have to dig a little deeper. Start by reading up on the software engineering principles. The SOLID principles are the most important but there are many others that you should abide by. One principle states that you should keep related data and behaviour together. Another states that each module(class) should have a single responsibility(reason to change). Most iOS developers follow the very bad development practice of loading the ViewControllers with all the application logic which violates many principles. Model classes are not just for storing state, they should also contain behaviour related to that state. A ViewController should not be accessing a database and should not know anything about the database. This should happen somewhere in your application model. If data is accessed in a specific way for each type then store that logic with the type. If much of it is the same for all types then abstract that part out.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for taking the time to respond. Trust me, I've read all of Firebase's documentation, many times (there's really not that much there). I agree with you/Firebase about flattening data structures, but that's where a lot of the issues come into play. I understand the SOLID principles and that's why I asked the question. For the sake of simplicity, I just said my data calls were on the VC, but they're actually in a separate class solely responsible for data. I understand this can be expanded to NoSQL/OO, but there are surely Firebase specific complications.

Comment: Hi, I would say that the complications are as much application specific as firebase specific. Rather than thinking about how other people might be doing it or how firebase is 'supposed' to be used, I would think more generally about what you want to achieve and how you can achieve it with the tools you have.

Comment: Obviously you want your functionality but you may also want things such as a minimal view controller and low coupling between data access and application logic. Think about your options and pick the one that makes the most sense for your particular goals. That most likely won't be the same as the best option for other people and their projects and it might have tradeoffs that you can't avoid.

Comment: At this point, I don't think that you will find any 'patterns' specific to firebase but there are many other patterns and design strategies that can be applied if you look at the problem more generally in the way I have mentioned. I know this isn't quite what you were looking for and I am essentially telling you to 'work it out yourself' but I hope this is at least a little bit helpful.